# Android Maps V2 not loading all locations

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, android-volley, android-maps-v2

I am having an issue with Google Maps API V2 on Android. I have a map in a ListView header which is parallaxed on scroll and that works fine. I had a problem, when I was popping the fragment managers back stack, that the map always became completely black with the google logo in the bottom corner. Then I found this issue on code.google.com : /p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4639

This helped me half way. Now I am using Lite Mode (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/lite) and facing weird errors. When I open the fragment it successfully shows all locations that are close to my current location (like its cached). But when I try to load a location in another country for example I get this line in the log:

```
05-20 14:24:50.636  16438-17496/com.anglingiq.android E/Volley﹕ [21005] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 404 for https://www.google.com/maps/vt/bpb=ChgiFgoGCOgCEPABEA8aCg3T9wonFZxAcvQSBggBGL-EPRoNEgVlbl9HQhoCR0IoASAAKgUtAABAQA==
```

And now the map fragment is black with grid, see picture:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/242865/2015-05-20.png

This log line above disturbs me, is it me doing something wrong or?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `Respond code` 404 not found, what do you mean by load data from another country? You may check the link.

Comment: This is not a request I send myself, the maps API does it. By saying from another country I mean that when the map I am loading is in the surrounding area the map is loaded successfully but when the map is loading some area that is not in the surrounding area, an area that is not cached, it is not loaded.

Comment: Try to save them into `object` or `Arraylist`.

Comment: I don't quite follow, I'm sorry. Save what in an Object / List ?